Can't connect to network after uninstalling PiHole and updating to Ubuntu 24.04
I've messed up my Ubuntu install, and I want to know if it can be fixed without re-installing.
The two main things that caused this problem, I think, are that I had PiHole installed on the server (and I was using the DHCP functionality), and I was using a PPA to install the most recent version of Python rather than the system version. Upon upgrading to 24.04, I found my Samba wasn't working anymore - when I tried re-installing Samba, it said my version of Python was bad, and as best I can tell, it's because I was using that PPA version of it. So, following some advice I found online, I uninstalled and re-installed Python, but doing so blew up the whole network since the server was acting as my DHCP server. I uninstalled PiHole and reset my router so my other devices could connect to the internet, but now the Ubuntu machine won't connect.
I have tried many, many things to fix it, but I'm out of my depth when it comes to this sort of Linux work. I can't ping to anything, and if I try to edit /etc/resolv.conf to change the nameserver, it just reverts back to the current value (127.0.0.53). I have seen suggestions to use
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
But I get a message that NetworkManager.service isn't found. My network adapter, eno1, is listed as down if I type
ip a
but typing
sudo ip link set eno1 up
Seems to bring it back up, but I still can't reach the internet. It just means that trying to ping something like google.com takes a few seconds to fail rather than failing instantly.
Happy to take any suggestions anyone has.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
